# Why Promise.catch() also call .then() if it is not in the right order?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know why the promise below both call the catch() and then() method.

```js
function testpromise(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    reject("Error");
  })
}


testpromise()
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
.then(()=>{console.log("Then")})
```

But why this one doesn't ? (I only moved the .then() method before the .catch() one).

```js
function testpromise(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    reject("Error");
  })
}


testpromise()
.then(()=>{console.log("Then")})
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
```

Is this a bug ? It's kind weird that I can't get the catch() method before the .then(). For me putting catch before then allow me to quickly check if I handle possible errors correctly. I have dozens of promises wrote like so and I just noticed that it will also call my .then() method right away, which is not good.

Comment: This is not a bug...it is by design. `catch()` returns a promise also which will be picked up by next then() in the chain if you don't throw again inside the catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A catch returns a promise so unless you throw or return another rejected promise it will resolve to the next then() in the chain

Following contrived  example should help you visualize it

```js
testpromise()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('First catch=', err)
    return 'Catch message'; // implicit return value, with no return next then receives undefined
  })
  .then((fromCatch) => {
    console.log("from first catch =", fromCatch)
  })
  .then(testpromise) // return another rejected promise to next catch
  .then(() => console.log('Not called'))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Second catch');
    throw 'New Error'
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Not called #2'))
  .then(() => console.log('Not called #3'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Final catch =', err))

function testpromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("Error");
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```
try {
  throw new Error("catch me if you can!");
} catch (err) {
  // whatever
}

console.log("hi");
```

Because that is the synchronous equivalent of this:

```
Promise.reject(new Error("catch me if you can!"))
  .catch(_ => { /* whatever */ })
  .then(_ => console.log("hi"));
```

Each time you add a `.then` or `.catch` it returns a *new* promise, it doesn't modify the old one in place. So it's not that the order is *wrong*, it's that it *matters*. Otherwise you couldn't do something like this:

```
fetch(someURL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(doSomethingWithJSON)
  .catch(err => {
     handleRequestFailure(err);
     console.error(err);
     return err;
  })
  .then(result => {
    if (result instanceof Error) {
      return fallbackRequest();
    }
  })
  .catch(handleFallbackError);
```

Answer (score 1):

> A .catch() is really just a .then() without a slot for a callback function for the case when the promise is resolved.

[MDN Promises Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Think of the `.then()` function as a chain, each one does something according to the resolved value, and passes the returned value to the next `.then()` in the chain, or if an error thrown, to the `.catch()` method.